# For each loop to display values from mysql table

Tags: php

In my table `courses` I have several entries that share the same `academy_id` value. I am using a foreach loop to retrieve all the rows with the same `academy_id`. In the example below, there is an academy that has two courses. The values are displaying correctly but there are some unnecessary values shown. For example it creates two results. Is it possible to have one combined result like shown below on the `wanted result to display` section?

*PHP*

```
$academy_id = 123

$db_select  = $db_con->prepare("
SELECT ca.course_name,
       ca.course_start_date,
       ca.course_end_date
FROM courses_by_academy ca
WHERE ca.academy_id = :academy_id
");
$final_result = '';
if (!$db_select) return false;
    if (!$db_select->execute(array(':academy_id' => $academy_id))) return false;
    $results = $db_select->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (empty($results)) return false;
    foreach ($results as $value){
    $final_result .= "<b>Academy Name: </b>".$value['name']."</br><b>Academy Type: </b>".$value['type']."</br><b>Status: </b>".$value['status']."</br>";
    $final_result .= "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['course_start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['course_end_date']."</br>";
    }
}
```

*Table Values*

```
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
| id | academy_id |     course_name      |  start_date   |  end_date  |
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
| 1  |        123 | Biology - Basic      | 2013-11-30    | 2013-12-25 |
| 2  |        123 | Biology - Nutrition  | 2014-01-15    | 2014-01-25 |
+----+------------+----------------------+---------------+------------+
```

*Current Result Displaying*

```
Academy Name: North Valley Schools
Academy Type: Post-Secondary
Status: INACTIVE
ID: 123
Course Name:  Biology - Basic  
Start date: 2013-11-30
End date: 2013-12-25

Academy Name: North Valley Schools
Academy Type: Post-Secondary
Status: INACTIVE
ID: 123
Course Name:  Biology - Nutrition 
Start date: 2014-01-15
End date: 2014-01
```

*Wanted Result- Combined*

```
Academy Name: North Valley Schools
Academy Type: Post-Secondary
Status: INACTIVE
ID: 123
Course Name:  Biology - Basic  
Start date: 2013-11-30
End date: 2013-12-25
Course Name:  Biology - Nutrition 
Start date: 2014-01-15
End date: 2014-01-25
```

Comment: You show column `$value['name']` and `$value['type'] for academy name/type that do not exist in the query result set.  How are you currently getting the display to actually work the way you have shown?  Second of all, if you are only ever querying for one academy at a time, why output the academy information inside the loop at all?  Simply move the display of the academy information outside the loop and leave the class-specific stuff inside it - problem solved.

Comment: @MarkBryant good point. How would it look like the academy information outside the loop? My mind can't grasp the concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop:

```
foreach ($results as $value){
   $final_result .= "<b>Academy Name: </b>".$value['name']."</br><b>Academy Type: </b>".$value['type']."</br><b>Status: </b>".$value['status']."</br>";
    $final_result .= "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['course_start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['course_end_date']."</br>";
}
```

instead do:

```
$first = true;
foreach ($results as $value){
    if($first){
        $first = false;
        $final_result .= "<b>Academy Name: </b>".$value['name']."</br><b>Academy Type: </b>".$value['type']."</br><b>Status: </b>".$value['status']."</br>"; 
    }
    $final_result .= "<b>Course Name: </b>".$value['course_name']."</br><b>Start Date: </b>".$value['course_start_date']."</br><b>End Date: </b>".$value['course_end_date']."</br>";
}
```

it will execute the academy information only once. :)

Comment: of course it is! I wrote it. ;)  heh.  j/k.  Im glad I could help.